# What are some Resources for Learning About Zmanim?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, time, zemanim, daytime

I'm interested in learning more about Zmanim, specifically, the different calculations involved and *how* to determine these times. I understand that the calculation of Zmanim can be complex, changing based on geographical location, the time of year, and other factors.

Could you please recommend some reliable resources (books, websites, online lectures, etc.) for a comprehensive understanding of this topic? I'm interested in both the theoretical knowledge and practical application of Zmanim in daily Jewish life.

Some resources that I found:

##### Books

- [Dvar Yom - An In-Depth Explanation of the Luach Based on Acharonim, Earlier and Present-Day Minhagim, and Astronomical Facts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1600912508)

##### Websites

- [About our Zmanim calculations - Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3209349/jewish/About-Our-Zmanim-Calculations.htm)
- [KosherJava.com](https://kosherjava.com/)

Comment: The two main disputes are how to divide the day into hours and when exactly bein hashmashos starts and ends. The groundbreaking Minchat Kohen (Pimentel) set the tone here for all later sefarim, and (with the warning to take his conclusions with a grain of salt) I'd recommend (subject to your abilities) starting there.

Comment: Zemanim.com has some good explanations regarding the various calculations.

Comment: I keep this open and it has some explanation https://www.myzmanim.com/day.aspx?vars=69553774

Comment: @DoubleAA I've been looking for a good sefer to start with this for a while as well. What do you mean by taking his conclusions with a grain of salt?

Comment: Mendel please clarify what your level of capabilities are. Can someone recommend an all Hebrew work? Gemaras and rishonim?

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend in English Shlomo Sternberg called [bein hashmashot](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjz1oenz6eAAxXmTaQEHT-LCJwQFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpeople.math.harvard.edu%2F%7Eshlomo%2Fdocs%2Fbeinhashemashot.pdf&usg=AOvVaw36a4VTzK5Ndc0bHHb43uBc&opi=89978449)
Or in Hebrew a book called [מעגלי צדק](https://biu.primo.exlibrisgroup.com/discovery/fulldisplay?vid=972BIU_INST:972BIU&docid=alma990001066690205776&lang=en&context=L&adaptor=Local%20Search%20Engine)
Also [זמנים בהלכה](https://www.lamdanbooks.co.il/product/%D7%94%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94) which is written by Beneish which is one of the best-researched books on the subject.

I would also caution that not all questions have answers on the subject.